# Pass parameter to custom controller's constructor from VF page which using it

Tags: visualforce

Assuming I have a controller class which I wants to initialize it's constructor with parameter, which will come from the VF page which using it for example :

```
global  class CppValidationCheckActivatorController {

private static boolean isFirst ;


global CppValidationCheckActivatorController(boolean isFirst ){
    this.isFirst  = isFirst  ; 
}
```

And the page should look like :

```
    <apex:page controller="CppValidationCheckActivatorController" 
<-- parameter sould be inserted here>>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `apex:component` or you can pass parameter in URL and then get them in `constructor`. You can't direct pass parameter using this approach.

Yes it is possible in apex to create parameterized constructor but you can't pass parameter from VF page in apex constructor without passing them in URL and then get them in constructor.

Because constructor is the first which loaded in processing.